# Laravel fill column value with default value while saving

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to fill the `token` field in `users` table with value while saving data to table.

How to achieve both in query builder and eloquent.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#observers

Comment: @ChristopherPecoraro can you let me know in query builder

Comment: Would you like to show your code in controller?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Model events adding a `boot method` into Model class like this.

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();
    static::created(function ($model) {
        $model->token = str_random(40);
    });
}
```

Also you can create an [observer](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent) to do the same and then to add the `protected $dispatchesEvents` array into the model.